# Drupal node revisions (content) not reflected after db restore

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I recently had an issue an issue after GoDaddy migrated to a new hosting provider...I was left with a fraction of the tables.  I had a backup from the previous week and restored the database.

The site is still intact, users, pages, modules etc etc, but the content is not reflected (outside statically created page content).  I can see the calendar entries, articles, content submissions etc in the node revisionm, field tables and other appropriate tables.

I made this as a favor a few years ago and was my one and only Drupal experience, so this may be too vague...but is there a way to rebuild the links to this content?

I am using Drupal 7.38.  Please let me know what pertinent information is further necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that database imported successfully.  Because i did it several time more then 20 and i did not get any error and any content missing issue.

Comment: I believe it imported correctly.  I can see all the data in the tables, just not reflected in on the site.